# Merge two lists which contains case class objects scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, mapreduce, monads

I have two lists which contains case class objects

```
case class Balance(id: String, in: Int, out: Int)

val l1 = List(Balance("a", 0, 0), Balance("b", 10, 30), Balance("c", 20, 0))

val l2 = List(Balance("a", 10, 0), Balance("b", 40, 0))
```

I want to sumup the elements in the tuples and combine the lists like below

```
List((Balance(a, 10, 0), Balance(b, 50, 30), Balance(c, 20, 0))
```

I have came with following solution

```
// create list of tuples with 'id' as key 
val a = l1.map(b => (b.id, (b.in, b.out)))
val b = l2.map(b => (b.id, (b.in, b.out)))

// combine the lists 
val bl = (a ++ b).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.unzip._2.unzip match {
  case (ll1, ll2)  => (ll1.sum, ll2.sum)
}).toList.map(b => Balance(b._1, b._2._1, b._2._2))

// output
// List((Balance(a, 10, 0), Balance(b, 50, 30), Balance(c, 20, 0))
```

Are they any shorter way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need to create the tuple lists.

```
(l1 ++ l2).groupBy(_.id)
          .mapValues(_.foldLeft((0,0)){
             case ((a,b),Balance(id,in,out)) => (a+in,b+out)})
          .map{
            case (k,(in,out)) => Balance(k,in,out)}
          .toList
// res0: List[Balance] = List(Balance(b,50,30), Balance(a,10,0), Balance(c,20,0))
```

You'll note that the result appears out of order because of the intermediate representation as a `Map`, which, by definition, has no order.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to add a `Semigroup` instance for `Balance` and use that for the *combine* logic. The advantage of this is that that code is in one place only, rather that sprinkled wherever you need to combine lists or maps of `Balance`s.

So, you first add the instance:

```
import cats.implicits._
implicit val semigroupBalance : Semigroup[Balance] = new Semigroup[Balance] 
{
   override def combine(x: Balance, y: Balance): Balance =
     if(x.id == y.id) // I am arbitrarily deciding this: you can adapt the logic to your 
                      // use case, but if you only need it in the scenario you asked for, 
                      // the case where y.id and x.id are different will never happen.
      Balance(x.id, x.in + y.in, x.out + y.out)
     else x
}
```

Then, the code to combine multiple lists becomes simpler (using your example data):

```
(l1 ++ l2).groupBy(_.id).mapValues(_.reduce(_ |+| _)) //Map(b -> Balance(b,50,30), a -> Balance(a,10,0), c -> Balance(c,20,0))
```

N.B. As @jwvh already noted, the result will not be in order, in this simple case, because of the default unordered `Map` the `groupBy` returns. That could be fixed, if needed.
N.B. You might want to use `Monoid` instead of `Semigroup`, if you have a meaningful `empty` value for `Balance`.

Answer (score 0):

For those who need to merge two list of case class objects, while maintaining the original ordering, here's my solution which is based on [jwvh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45809767/855838) to this question and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14434208/855838).

```
import scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap

val mergedList: List[Balance] = l1 ++ l2

val sortedListOfBalances: List[Balance] =
         SortedMap(mergedList.groupBy(_.id).toSeq:_*)
         .mapValues(_.foldLeft((0,0)){
           case ((a,b),Balance(id,in,out)) => (a+in,b+out)
         })
         .map{
           case (k,(in,out)) => Balance(k,in,out) 
         }
         .toList
```

This will return `List(Balance(a,10,0), Balance(b,50,30), Balance(c,20,0))` while when not using `SortedMap` we get `List(Balance(b,50,30), Balance(a,10,0), Balance(c,20,0))`.

`map` always returns in an unspecified order unless we specifically use a subtype of `SortedMap`.