# Join two lists of case classes and output new class with difference between two

Tags: scala

I have two lists of case classes of the same type:

```
case class ScoreOutput = (id: String, runDate: String, score: Double)
val originalScores: List[ScoreOutput] = List(
    ScoreOutput(1, "09-21", 5.0), 
    ScoreOutput(2, "09-21", 3.0),
    ScoreOutput(3, "09-21", 2.0)
)

val currentScores: List[ScoreOutput] = List(
    ScoreOutput(1, "10-01", 20.0), 
    ScoreOutput(2, "10-01", 1.0),
    ScoreOutput(3, "10-01", 18.0)
)
```

I need to combine the two lists into a new list of a new type

```
case class ScoreComparison(name: String, originalDate: String, currentDate: String, scoreChange: Double)

val scoreDiff: List[ScoreComparison] = // concatenate two lists, groupby name and fold two lists into new type?
```

where scoreDiff would be

```
List(
    ScoreComparison(1, "09-21", "10-01", 15.0), 
    ScoreComparison(2, "09-21", "10-01", -2.0), 
    ScoreComparison(3, "09-21", "10-01", 16),
    )
```

what is the best way to accomplish this? I was going to use the method in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45809767/7948380 but I need to keep track of which value in the group by is from the `originalScores` list and which is from the `currentScores` list. If I concatenate the lists like this `(originalScores ++ currentScore)` and then do a groupBy on the concatenated list, am I guaranteed the values in the group by will be in order they appeared in the concatenated list (meaning, will the first item of the groupBy always represent the value from `originalScores`?

Comment: Not clear but from your example `zip` would do the trick.

Comment: If you have **cats** in scope, you may convert both `Lists` into two `Maps` whose keys are the ids, and then use `alignWith` to combine them.