# Concatenation of Sets in Scala, unexpected results

Tags: scala

The following is a bit of code adapted from an online Scala tutorial:

```
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val fruit1 = List("apples", "oranges", "pears")
      val fruit2 = List("mangoes", "banana")
      val veg1 = Set("potatoes", "carrots", "peas")
      val veg2 = Set("cabbage", "squash")

      var fruit = fruit1 ++ fruit2
      println( "fruit1 ++ fruit2 : " + fruit )
      var vegetable = veg1 ++ veg2
      println( "veg1 ++ veg2 : " + vegetable )
   }
}
```

And here are the results:

fruit1 ++ fruit2 : List(apples, oranges, pears, mangoes, banana)

veg1 ++ veg2 : Set(cabbage, peas, squash, carrots, potatoes)

The List concatenation works as I expected, but I would never have predicted the resulting order of the Set concatenation. Can anyone explain how the results are arrived at? The online tutorial is not much help here.

Comment: What was your expectation for the ordering of `Set`? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5246204/409976

Comment: The least surprising result would have been the three items of veg1 followed by the two items of veg2. Just like the result obtained by List concatenation.

Answer (score 6):

`scala.collection.Set` doesn't provide any guarantees about traversal order—if you ask for a string representation of one, the order you get is unspecified and depends on the implementation.

Some subclasses of `scala.collection.Set` *do* provide guarantees about order—e.g. the ordering you see when iterating through a `collection.immutable.SortedSet` will depend on the `Ordering` instance that you used to construct the set, and `collection.mutable.LinkedHashSet` will iterate through its elements in insertion order. When you're working with an arbitrary `Set`, though, you should never, ever, rely on the order that you happen to see when using `toString`, `foreach`, etc.

Comment: "doesn't provide any guarantees about traversal order" ~ I figured on something like this as an answer, yet "veg1.head" and returns the first item of the Set. And it does so fairly reliably.

Comment: @MartinTrueman The default representation of mall sets (four elements or fewer) that you get with `Set.apply` _happens_ to maintain insertion order (in theory this could change at any moment, though). For anything larger than that, `head` returning the "first" element (by insertion order) is an accident.

Comment: Very interesting. With 5 or more items in the Set, the "head" function is not at all reliable. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: @MartinTrueman Well, technically it's never "reliable"—it just happens to be consistent for small sets. :)

Comment: I should add that if I pare down the sizes of my Sets and concatenate two Sets of two items each yielding a single Set of four elements, the "head" function works and the ordering is the same as the List ordering.

Answer (score 2):

Note that since `Set` is an unordered data structure, implementations are free to use any order they like.

The default implementation of `Set` uses a `HashSet` under the hood. This is implemented using a hashing approach which makes O(n) to determine whether an item exists in the Set. The ordering on output is probably the order of the hashes generated per item, which is effectively random.

An alternative implementation is `TreeSet`, which stores the data as a tree, so is O(log(n)) to determine whether an item exists in the set. In this case, the output ordering is the order of the items as they would be in a Tree.

The following code demonstrates this:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.{TreeSet, HashSet}

val veg1 = HashSet("potatoes", "carrots", "peas")
val veg2 = HashSet("cabbage", "squash")
val vegetable = veg1 ++ veg2
println( "veg1 ++ veg2 : " + vegetable )
//veg1 ++ veg2 : Set(cabbage, peas, squash, carrots, potatoes)

val trVeg1 = TreeSet("potatoes", "carrots", "peas")
val trVeg2 = TreeSet("cabbage", "squash")
val trVegetable = trVeg1 ++ trVeg2
println( "trVeg1 ++ trVeg2 : " + trVegetable )
//trVeg1 ++ trVeg2 : TreeSet(cabbage, carrots, peas, potatoes, squash)
```

EDIT:

As pointed out in the comments by Travis Brown, it's not exactly true that the "default implementation" of Set is a HashSet. Scala has specific implementations of `Set` when there's a small number of items, However when a set of more than 4 items is created, or when the `++` operator is used on instances of `Set()` to create a `Set` of more than 4 items, the result is a HashSet:

```
val set1 = Set("abc", "def", "ghi")

val set2 = Set("abcd", "defg", "ghij")

set1.getClass
//scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set3

set2.getClass
//scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set3

val concSet = set1 ++ set2

concSet.getClass
//scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet
```

The small Set implementations only go up to Sets of 4 items, so:

```
val set3 = Set("abcd", "defg", "ghij", "fghtre", "dfghdd")

set3.getClass
//scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet
```

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Set.scala#L184

Comment: It's not strictly true that the default implementation of `Set` uses a hashset (if by "default implementation" you mean what you get from `Set.apply`, `toSet`, etc.)—for small sets it will be `Set.SetN`.

Comment: Sorry to nit-pick, but your update ("when the `++` operator is used…") still isn't literally accurate—e.g. `(Set(1, 2) ++ Set(3, 4)).getClass`.