# Is there a specific order of insertion of an element to a set?

Tags: scala, set, scala-collections

When I was trying to insert an element to a scala mutable set, I got the following output.

My code was as follows.

```scala
object sets{
  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit={
    var set1 = Set(1,2,3,4);
    println(set1);
    println(set1.+(6));
  }
}
```

And the output was as follows.

```
Set(1,2,3,4)
Set(1,6,2,3,4)
```

Is there a specific reason for 6 being printed after 1 instead of after 4?

Comment: A `Set` has no order: `println(Set(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order in the set does not depend on when you insert the elements. To be fair, the idea of order in a set does not really make sense since a set is an unordered collection.

If you want to understand why you see this order, this has to do with the hashcode of the objects. I recommend reading the [Wikipedia article about Hashtables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

If you need to preserve the order in which you insert your object, you could use a `List`. To keep the uniqueness of the elements inside your collection, you can use `List.distinct`.

Answer (score 2):

[`LinkedHashSet`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/LinkedHashSet.html) preserves the order of insertion like so

```
val set1 = LinkedHashSet(1,2,3,4)
println(set1)
println(set1 += 6)
```

which outputs

```
LinkedHashSet(1, 2, 3, 4)
LinkedHashSet(1, 2, 3, 4, 6)
```

as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5246204/5205022)

> You need to preserve the order in which the items are inserted. Then
>   you use the `LinkedHashSet`. Practically as fast as the normal `HashSet`,
>   needs a little more storage space for the additional links between
>   elements.

Note `LinkedHashSet`, like other sets, will not keep duplicates, that is,

```
assert(set1 == (set1 += 1)) // passes
```

If you do not require uniqueness of elements, then consider going with `List`.

Comment: `ListSet` is sufficient to preserve order

Comment: @cchantep OP seems to ask for a mutable set.

Comment: Then `SortedSet` is sufficient, not to couple w/ specific impl, except if explicitly wanted