# Does Scala have a 'unique list' type?

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-2.10

I'm looking for something like the **immutable** `SortedSet`, except I want elements to be ordered in the sequence they were passed into the constructor.

```
UniqueList(4,2,3,1,1) // Throws exception
UniqueList(4,2,3,1) // Iterator yields: 4,2,3,1
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `collection.mutable.LinkedHashSet` - it has unique elements and traversal occurs in the order that the elements were added.

Comment: Is there an immutable alternative?

Comment: There is the `immutable.ListMap`, but it has `O(n)` lookup time. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313866/immutable-scala-map-implementation-that-preserves-insertion-order

Comment: Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding Maps in Scala, but aren't they a key->value collection? I'm only interested in values...

Comment: I meant an `immutable.ListSet`. In the related question the technique could be applied to the sets in a similar way.

Comment: This question highlights problems with using this type for an insertion ordered set. The items appear to be reversed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481925/ordered-listset

Answer (score 1):

There's [ListSet](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.ListSet), although it will have the values in the reverse order that they were passed into the constructor.

```
scala> import scala.collection.immutable.ListSet
import scala.collection.immutable.ListSet

scala> ListSet(1,2,3,4)
res7: scala.collection.immutable.ListSet[Int] = ListSet(4, 3, 2, 1)
```